# Voltage ramp with split power supply

Tags: split-supply

I want to create an controllable output voltage from -2.5 to +2.5 on the R8 resistor.

My circuit is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVQf9D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So my microcontroller controls the DAC, which outputs from 5V to 0V. This output goes to Differential amplifier (AMP2), which should give me max:

2.5V-0 = +2.5V

and min:

2.5V-5V = -2.5V

Across the R8

Did I use the reference voltages (VGND and GND) correct?

I have a slight confusion:

Will the AMP2 see the 5V from the DAC as 5V and subtract it? Or it will see the 5V from DAC as 2.5V?

I think, because DAC is connected to GND (and not VGND) , the AMP2 will see the 5V from the DAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simulated my circuit, and even though I did not put a DAC, I think its pretty accurate simulation:

[image: My simulation -2.5V]

My output (on R8) goes to -2.5V as I wanted it to be.

[image: my simu +2.5V]

And on +2.5V as I want it to be.

I also figured out I do not need the AMP2 (The differencial op amp). I can have +2.5 and -2.5 directly from DAC:

[image]

[image]